# If do retorno de função não reconhece true, apenas false

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho esse código abaixo, que era pra se a função retornar true, ele executar o if. Porém ele só executa o if se eu alterar o if para false, ou seja, colocando "if(!linkAlreadySent)" invés de "if(linkAlreadySent)". Alguém sabe apontar o problema?

```
var link = "http://www.google.com";

function linkAlreadySent(link) {
    mysql.handle.query('SELECT link FROM links WHERE link = ?', [link], function (err, res) {
        if(res.length == 1) {
            console.log('Retornando true, o link ja existe');
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log('Retornando false, o link não existe');
            return false;
        }
    });
}

if(linkAlreadySent(link)) {
  console.log('Entrou no if');
}
```

Comment: Não entendi bem o que quer fazer, mas, faz assim `var teste = linkAlreadySent(link)` e dá um **console.log** em teste pra ver o que retorna.

Comment: A função linkAlreadySent consulta a tabela para verificar se o registro do link já existe na coluna "link". Se existir, retorna true. Se não, false. O if logo abaixo irá ser chamado se a função retornar true

Comment: João, a função `linkAlreadySent` não está retornando nada. Quem está retornando `true` ou `false` é a função declarada como callback do método `mysql.handle.query`. Para a função `linkAlreadySent` retornar algo, você precisa declarar esse retorno fora de funções internas. Mas aí você vai precisar tratar o asincronismo desse código, você já é familiar com isso ou precisa de uma resposta?

Comment: Hmmm, talvez seja isso mesmo @user140828. Mas não sou muito familiar com isso, pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o seu `return` está dentro da função de `callback` de `mysql.handle.query`. A função de callback está retornando uma valor, mas `linkAlreadySent` não.

Bom, na verdade, `linkAlreadySent` está retornando `undefined`, pois toda função sem um retorno explicito retorna `undefined` em JS. `undefined` é um valor "falsy", ele é tratado como falso quando você o utiliza com condição. Então como `linkAlreadySent` retorna `undefined`, e você utiliza esse retorno em `if(linkAlreadySent(link))` você nunca cai dentro do `if`.

---

Como tratar o problema?

Não é tão simples quanto retornar o retorno de `mysql.handle.query`. O `thread` principal do JS não espera por processos de entrada e saída para continuar rodando o código. Quando você faz uma query no banco de dados, o JS continua rodando a função até o final, sai da função, e eventualmente quando o banco de dados devolve uma resposta, o JS executa a função de callback que você declarou. Nesse momento já é tarde demais para retornar um valor pela função `linkAlreadySent`, pois ela já terminou de rodar.

---

A abordagem funcional

Você pode passar uma função para `linkAlreadySent` executar quando ela receber a resposta do banco de dados. Da seguinte maneira:

```
var link = "http://www.google.com";

function linkAlreadySent(link, callback) {
    mysql.handle.query('SELECT link FROM links WHERE link = ?', [link], function (err, res) {
        if(res.length == 1) {
            console.log('Retornando true, o link ja existe');
            // A função é invocada se você entrar na condição desejada
            callback(res);
        } else {
            console.log('Retornando false, o link não existe');
        }
    });
}

// Passo o link e uma função anonima como parametros
linkAlreadySent(link, (res) => {
    console.log('Entrou no "if"');
});
```

---

A abordagem procedural

Com a utilização de `promises`, você pode "pausar" a função (mas não a `thread` principal) até você obter a resolução da `promise`. `Promise` é basicamente um objeto que empacota uma resposta, quando você obtêm a resolução da resposta, basta desempacota-la da `promise`. Fazemos isso com o operador `await`.

```
// Módulo do NodeJS
var util = require('util');

var link = "http://www.google.com";

// Crio uma nova função que retorna promises
var mysqlQuery = util.promisify(mysql.handle.query);

// Funções precisam do modificador async para poderem utilizar await
// Toda função do tipo async retorna resultados empacotados em promises
async function linkAlreadySent(link) {
    // Espero pela resposta
    var res = await mysqlQuery('SELECT link FROM links WHERE link = ?', [link]);

    if (res.length == 1) {
        console.log('Retornando true, o link ja existe');
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log('Retornando false, o link não existe');
        return false;
    }
}

async verificaLink() {
    // Novamente, utilizamos await, pois o retorno de linkAlreadySent está empacotado
    if (await linkAlreadySent(link)) {
        console.log('Entrou no if');
    }
}

verificaLink();
```

Comment: Agora eu entendi o que você quis dizer. NA [API mysql-libmysqlclient](https://sannis.github.io/node-mysql-libmysqlclient/api/) cada função tem duas versões uma é síncrona e outra é assíncrona, a diferença é que a funções sincronas tem o sufixo `Sync` na frente das funções. Visto isso você tem razão meu código não funciona. Estou o retirando minha resposta.

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente, obrigado!!